# Google Data Studio - stepped configuration issue

Tags: google-apps-script, looker-studio

In my connector the initial configuraton allows to browse through categories and subcategories in order to choose what data will be fetched. Choosing a parent category triggers an API call to fetch subcategories etc. The problem is that basically user can stop at choosing `Main Category > Subcategory` as well as `Main Category > Subcategory > Sub Subcategory > Sub Sub Subcategory..etc`. So I actually don't know when I should set `setIsSteppedConfig(false)`. If I do it too early I remove the ability to browse to the most specific category. If do it at the last subcategory level I remove the ability to choose more general categories. As far as I understand the idea of stepped configurations presumes that developer knows precisely when the user is done configuring. Like for example in Google Analytics you cannot stop at choosing `account` or `property` but you have to select a `view`.
In my case it is different because user can stop at any category level (except the first one). Has anyone come up with the solution for this kind of issue?

Answer (score 2):

Probably the easiest way to get this to work is adding a checkbox at the bottom of your config called something like "choose this level." Then in your connector code you can check to see if that field is selected and if so, call `setIsSteppedConfig(false)`.

It's not the most elegant workaround, but it's a way to get information from the user that they've selected the level/hierarchy they're interested in.

Comment: Good idea. It might just work :). I wish I knew how they do it in the official Google Analytics connector where you don't actually go through steps by clicking `next` button but still somehow they are able to react to user clicks. It looks like they're using some feature that's not documented. Anyway thanks for the tip!